# Wrong value for hour, minutes and mills when parsing date string to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'-'hh:mm"

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I've been experimenting with different formats for a while now. But I encountered a problem when parsing a date string to a date.

Here's the sample date string I'm trying to parse. "2015-04-13T10:17:00-04:00"

Here's my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'-'hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                startCal.setTime(format.parse(data.StartTime));
                endCal.setTime(format.parse(data.EndTime));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The value that I'm getting when printing it on the log is

```
Log.i("Event exact date", String.valueOf(startCal.getTime().toString()));

04-13 22:38:11.526: I/Event exact date(1665): Mon Apr 13 04:00:00 GMT+08:00 2015
```

I was expecting the hour value to be 10 and minutes to be 17. I think it is getting the value from the "-hh:mm". I'm getting this value from a web api. Any ideas guys? Thanks

Comment: What do you expect it to do with the second time arguments? As is, it currently overrides the first one.

Comment: I think the last hour/minute part is really a time zone offset. You need to parse it as that, not hours/minutes.

Comment: @haraldK how do i represent offset in that kind of format?

Comment: @Aru do you mean this? endCal.setTime(format.parse(data.EndTime)); this is a excess code. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not need "-04:00" zone offset (timezone) then just truncate string "2015-04-13T10:17:00-04:00" to "2015-04-13T10:17:00"

```
        String fullDate = "2015-04-13T10:17:00-04:00";
        String truncatedDate = fullDate.substring(0, fullDate.lastIndexOf('-'));

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {

            Date dte = format.parse(truncatedDate);
            System.out.println("date=" + dte);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Result is:

> date=Mon Apr 13 10:17:00 CEST 2015

Comment: This does work. I would prefer having the date remained the same without manipulating it. By I guess this is the only way? Thanks mate!

Comment: Unless your local timezone is also GMT-04:00 you need to somehow compensate for that, otherwise the times will be off.

Comment: will not work if your time zone is +08:00 like what the question states.

Answer (score 2):

I think the format you want is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Where the 'XXX', according to [SimpleDateFormat API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), means ISO 8601 time zone.

Full example:

```
public class TestDateParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date date = format.parse("2015-04-13T10:17:00-04:00");
        System.out.println("date: " + date);
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
date: Mon Apr 13 16:17:00 CEST 2015
```

Comment: Tried this but as expected there's an error in parsing cause the format do not match.

Comment: @ljpv14 Strange... The example in the docs shows time zone as `XXX`. However, both `X` and `XXX` works for me in normal Java (JDK 1.7). An Android issue?

Comment: Edited my comment. Sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

use Z for timezone. It should work.

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

for reference, this is the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes. Avoid them.

Use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Look for back-ports [for Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Your input string happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 as their defaults when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### Offset

That last part `-04:00` is indeed an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) as mentioned in other Answers. It means the date-time shown is four hours behind [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
String input = "2015-04-13T10:17:00-04:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

### Time Zone

You can search [the list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to see which zones use that particular offset of `-04:00`. I see a few dozen zones with that offset.

If you know the intended time zone, apply it (a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)). A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) *plus* the rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). So using a time zone is always better than a mere offset, provided you are certain of the correct zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Puerto_Rico" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId );
```

### UTC

The [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) objects seen above represent the very same moment on the timeline. If you want to see that moment in UTC, as for an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();  // …or…
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();  // Both instants are the same moment on the timeline in UTC.
```